# Daily Bulk Loading and Updating of MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working to build a partial copy of a DB that will be used for reporting.  I would like to build the second DB in MySQL.  The MySQL DB will have two main tables.  One table will have about 100 new rows that need to be added each day and about 300 that need to be updated.  The table will have about 20 columns of mostly ~20 character text fields.  The second table will have about 1,000 new rows each day and about 3,000 updates.  This table will have about 40 fields with about half being date fields and the other have being ~ 10 character text fields.

Each day I will receive a tab delimited file that has the combined updated and new rows in it.

Here were some ways that I was thinking of doing the updates and inserts.  Are there options that I am missing that I should be looking at?  Any advice on what would be the best approach?

Option 1 - Split the file into inserts and updates.  Use the FILE option on an insert to load them.  build and run update statements for the update.

Option 2 - Load the entire file into a temp table that then use a join to find and update rows and then insert the new rows.

Option 3 - Build inserts on everything with the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

My updates and inserts to the data will be the only non-read operation on the data each day.  Eventually I want to automate the process so that it runs overnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a large amount of operations per day.  All options will work just fine.

Options 1 or 3 are probably the simplest and therefore most likely to

- Be implemented error free
- Be easy for any future maintainer

Option 3 is not directly portable to other databases, should that ever matter.

Comment: You're not loading a lot of data, but it will be more efficient to update first then load new records. Hopefully, the data you are inserting or updating is consistent and of good quality. I run into more issues loading data than performance with inserts, updates...

Comment: Yes, data cleansing is often a significant topic when dealing with data transfers between systems in the form of flat files.

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback!  For about 4 years we have been doing a weekly report with just a few months of data (data is purged and reloaded each week.)  Blank values, where there shouldn't be, is the largest issue we have today.  Hopefully that shouldn't be a huge issue to deal with.  We have an excel macro that we use today to fix the blanks.